# Flutter Project - Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch

Tags: flutter, gradle, dependencies, overriding

I'm trying to update a project in Flutter and when I want to run it, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:123)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1513)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1484)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1069)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:282)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:141)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3678)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3671)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:62)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode$GCMDecrypt.doFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:1486)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.engineDoFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:447)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2500)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T12GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1659)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    ... 17 more
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

When a do "flutter doctor -v" i have this result:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2846], locale
    es-419)
    • Flutter version 2.8.0 at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cf44000065 (1 year, 5 months ago), 2021-12-08 14:06:50 -0800     
    • Engine revision 40a99c5951
    • Dart version 2.15.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\RUFDev\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33-ext5, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java      
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio      
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)

[√] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\RUFDev\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.62.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 12 (API 31)        
      (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      112.0.5615.138
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge
      112.0.1722.58

• No issues found!
```

My "pubspec.yaml" have this:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.7
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  enum_to_string: ^1.0.14
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.2
  firebase_core: ^1.1.0
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.5.1
  flutter_rating_bar: ^3.2.0+1
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.0
  flutter_camera_overlay: ^0.1.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.4.0
  future_progress_dialog: ^0.1.1
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  logger: ^1.1.0
  permission_handler: ^8.3.0
  provider: ^6.0.2
  string_validator: ^0.1.4
  uuid: ^3.0.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  geolocator: ^8.1.1
  square_percent_indicater: ^0.1.0
  internet_connection_checker: ^0.0.1+3
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  sn_progress_dialog: ^1.0.3
  lottie: ^1.2.2
  camera: ^0.9.4+16
  image_cropper: ^1.5.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.4
  badges: ^2.0.2
  flutter_sound: ^9.2.10
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  url_launcher: ^6.1.0
  fancy_shimmer_image: ^2.0.2
  in_app_review: ^2.0.4
  twilio_flutter: ^0.0.9
  record_mp3: ^3.0.0
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.1.8+4
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I'm using Flutter 2.8 and Gradle 7.3.3.

I already made several attempts with different versions of Flutter, but when updating I have to modify the code a lot due to changes in libraries and dependencies (I tried to change everything using the latest Flutter and I have some errors in debug mode that I cannot solve and for that reason I have returned to the original project).

I have JAVA Azul 8, 11, 15 and 17 installed, and I am testing with emulators with Android 11 and 12.

Some friends told me to override some dependencies, but I don't know which ones or which one is the most appropriate.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be anything to do with your Flutter version or project. Gradle is trying to download something and the TLS/HTTPS socket gets broken with bad encryption. Try working out with Gradle logging or wireshark which server it is talking to when it breaks.

Comment: But with other projects or a new project a don't have this problem. Only with this project